# How to solve the following minimizing problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Find arg min$_A$$\frac{1}{2}||X − SA||_F^2$,

where $||·||_F$ is the Frobenius norm of a matrix: $||Y||_F=\sqrt{tr(Y^TY))}$, and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{L\times N}$, $S\in \mathbb{R}^{L\times P}$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{P\times N}$ are matrics.

I only dealt with second norm of a matrix before, and don't know how to deal with the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the Frobenius norm acts like the 2-norm.  Although it's possible just to vectorize everything out, I prefer to solve these problems in block form.  Mostly, we just need some rules for doing calculus on matrices.

Note, the Frobenius norm defines an inner product.  Hence, we have
$$
f(x) = \|x\|^2_F = tr(x^Tx) = \langle x,x\rangle 
$$
Then, using Tailor series, we can get the derivatives:
$$
f(x+\delta x) = \langle x + \delta x,x + \delta x\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle + 2\langle x,\delta x\rangle + \langle \delta x,\delta x\rangle
$$
Since Tailor's theorem tells us that
$$
f(x + \delta x) = f(x) + f^\prime(x)\delta x + f^{\prime\prime}(x)\delta x\delta x + \dots
$$
we can match terms and get that
$$
f^\prime(x)\delta x = 2\langle x,\delta x\rangle
$$
or that
$$
\nabla f(x) = 2x.
$$

Going back to your problem, let me change the notation to solving
$$
\arg\min_{X}\|AX - B\|^2_F = g(X)
$$
The first order necessary conditions require that
$$
\nabla g(X) = 0
$$
From above and the chain rule, we have that
$$
g^\prime(X) = 2\langle AX-B,A\delta X\rangle = 2\langle A^T(AX-B),\delta X\rangle
$$
This implies that
$$
\nabla g(X) = 2A^T(AX-B)
$$
Hence, we're optimal when
$$
2A^T(AX-B) = 0
$$
or
$$
A^TAX = A^TB
$$
which is essentially what we have if we had vectors.

Practically speaking, we solve this doing the exact same thing as we would with a vector equation.  However, here, we have multiple right hand sides, $A^TB$.  As such, it really comes down to whether or not $A^TA$ is full rank or not.  The easy answer is to just say use the psuedo inverse.  If we want to be more saavy, if $A$ is tall and skinny, do a QR factorization of it, which will transform $A^TA$ into $R^TR$ where $R$ is upper triangular, so a couple of back solves will solve the equation.  When $A$ is short and fat, we can still use the QR factorization.  Let $A=QR$ and then set $B=R^T(RR^T)^{-2}R$.  The matrix $BA$ has eigenvalues of only 1 or 0, so if we use $B$ as a preconditioner with a Krylov method, it'll converge in one iteration.  The reason that works is that
$$
BA^TA = (R^T(RR^T)^{-2}R)(QR)^TQR = (R^T(RR^T)^{-2}R)R^TR = R^T(RR^T)^{-1}R
$$
which is an orthogonal projector, so it only has eigenvalues of 0 or 1.  Technically, when $A$ is not full rank, we have to be a little more careful in both approaches.  However, smart use of a rank-revealing QR factorization will essentially allow the same tricks to work.

Long story short, it's just the normal equations with multiple right hand sides.

Comment: fantastic answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem; glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the problem column-wise, you will see that this is just the usual least-square problem. There may be infinitely many global minimisers, but among all of them, the one with the least Frobenius norm is given by $A_0=S^+X$, where $S^+$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $S$. All other global minimisers are obtained by adding to each column of $A_0$ some vector in $\ker S$ (and hence the minimiser is unique if $S$ has full column rank).